# Using an ArrayList in Another Class to scan through objects

Tags: java, arraylist, jframe

I'm trying to scan though an AraayList created in the main class, in the turtle class to check various criteria. I simplified the code as much as possible for you.

The main class:

```js
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

class TurtleProgram
{ 
 public ArrayList<DynamicTurtle> turtles;

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  new TurtleProgram();
 }

 public TurtleProgram()
 {
  //INSTANTIATED JFRAME WITH BUTTONS/SLIDER AND CREATED LISTENER METHODS

  turtles = new ArrayList<DynamicTurtle>(); //THE ARRAYLIST I AM WANTING TO USE IN ANOTHER CLASS
  turtles.add(new RandomTurtleB(canvas, 400, 300, 100, 0)); //THIS ARRAYLIST BECOMES LARGER WHEN BUTTONS ON JFRAME TO ADD NEW TURTLES
  
  gameLoop(); //LOOP FOREVER
 }   

 private void gameLoop() 
 {
  int deltaTime = 20;
  
  while(true)
  {
   for (int i = 0; i < turtles.size(); i++)
   {
    (turtles.get(i)).unDrawTurtle(); //REMOVE FROM CANVAS    
    (turtles.get(i)).wrapPosition((turtles.get(i)).getPositionX(), (turtles.get(i)).getPositionY()); //MAKE SURE TURTLES NOT OFF SCREEN
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < turtles.size(); i++)
   {
    (turtles.get(i)).update(1000); //MAKE THE TURTLES MOVE WITH A CHANCE OF TURNING
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < turtles.size(); i++)
   {
    (turtles.get(i)).drawTurtle(); //DRAW TO CANVAS   
   }

   for(int i = 0; i < turtles.size(); i++)
   {
    (turtles.get(i)).cohesian(); //THIS IS HOW I WOULD LIKE TO ADDRESS THE COHESIAN METHOD
   }
  
  
  Utils.pause(deltaTime/2);
  } 
 }
}
```

Then I would like to check the current turtle against other turtles to see if it's close in the cohesion() method to perform actions:

```js
class Turtle 
{
    protected Canvas canvas; // private field reference to a canvas private           
    private CartesianCoordinate myLocation, oldLocation; 
    private boolean penDown = true;
    private double angle, maxX, maxY, nowPosX, nowPosY, maximumX, maximumY, x, y;
    public double d, e, first, second; 
    private int speed;   

    public Turtle(Canvas canvas, CartesianCoordinate initLocation) 
    {
        this.canvas = canvas;
        this.myLocation = new CartesianCoordinate(0,0);        
        penDown = true;
        myLocation = initLocation.copy();        
    }      

    public void cohesian()
    {
        double flockingDistanceLimit = 200;
        double numberOfFlockers = 0;
        double combinedX = 0;
        double combinedY = 0;
        double averageCombinedX, averageCombinedY, averageCombinedY,  moveToFlock, turnToFlock, distanceToPotentialFlock;        

        for (DynamicTurtle t : turtles) //CANNOT USE THE ARRAYLIST TO SCAN THROUGH ITS ELEMENTS
        {
            if(this.getPositionX() != t.getPositionX() && this.getPositionY() != t.getPositionY()) //MAKE SURE TURTLE ISNT SCANNING ITS SELF
            {
                distanceToPotentialFlock = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((this.getPositionX()-t.getPositionX()),2 ) + Math.pow((this.getPositionY()-this.getPositionY()),2)); //FIND DISTANCE BETWEEN CURRENT AND SCANNED TURTLE

                if(distanceToPotentialFlock < flockingDistanceLimit) //MAKE SURE THE FOUND TURTLE IS WITHIN RANGE USING THE DISTANCE BETWEEN POINTS METHOD
                {
                    combinedX = combinedX + t.getPositionX(); //FIND SUMMATION OF X POSITIONS
                    combinedY = combinedY + t.getPositionY(); //FIND SUMMATION OF Y POSITIONS
                    numberOfFlockers++; //AS A FLOCKER HAS BEEN FOUND INCREMENT THE NUMBER OF FLOCKERS
                }
            }

            if(numberOfFlockers > 0)
            {
                averageCombinedX = (combinedX / numberOfFlockers); //FIND AVERAGE X POSITION
                averageCombinedY = (combinedY / numberOfFlockers); //FIND AVERAGE Y POSITION
                moveToFlock = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(averageCombinedX,2 ) + Math.pow(averageCombinedY, 2)); //CALCULATE DISTANCE TO CENTER OF FLOCKING
                turnToFlock = Math.atan(averageCombinedY / averageCombinedX);

                if(turnToFlock < 0)
                {
                    turnToFlock = 360 - (-turnToFlock); //ADJUSTING FOR NEGATIVES
                }
            }
        }
    }  

    public void wrapPosition(double x, double y) 
    {
        this.maxX = x;
        this.maxY = y; 

        if(maxX < 0)
        {
            this.setPositionX(800);
        }

        else if(maxX > 800)
        {
            this.setPositionX(0);
        }

        if(maxY < 0)
        {
            this.setPositionY(600);
        }

        else if(maxY > 600)
        {
            this.setPositionY(0);
        }        
    }
}
```

If I could have any help with using the ArrayList in the Turtle Class, in the cohesian() method, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Either pass the arrayList as parameter to cohesian, or declare it as a static field

Comment: Hello @aviad, I have tried adding the arraylist as a parameter: { (turtles.get(i)).cohesian(turtles); } and the the cohesion method so allow an arraylist as follows: { public static void cohesian(ArrayList<DynamicTurtle> turtles) } but i still cannot get it to work, could you help further? Cheers.

Comment: Pass the same parameter to gameLoop the same way

Comment: Thanks for replying @aviad, However I am now getting an error stating "error: cannot find symbol" in "public void cohesian(ArrayList<DynamicTurtle> turtles) saying it cannot find symbol. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Thankyou for your help over the last hour or so, the reason why nothing was working was because i didn't import java.util.ArrayList; at the top of the Turtle Class.